# How to export a jquery varaible as html file

Tags: jquery, html

I wants to export a jquery variable as html file on button click with the following code.

```
var html = buildSource(htmleditor, jseditor, csseditor);

$('#hitbookmark').click(function(){
downloadInnerHtml(html, 'main','text/html');
});

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
var elHtml = html;
mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

link.setAttribute('download', filename);
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
link.click(); 

}
```

please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
//var html = buildSource(htmleditor, jseditor, csseditor);
var html = '<div>DEMO</div>';

$('#hitbookmark').on('click', function() {
  downloadInnerHtml(html, 'main', 'text/html');
});

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
  mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
  var blob = new Blob([html], {
    type: mimeType
  });
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  link.download = filename;

  // Fix Firefox problem
  link.style.display = 'none';
  body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  body.removeChild(link);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="hitbookmark">Download</button>
```

Hope to help you:)